# Are you able to commit to teach, or are you able to be committed to teach?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Question: Are you able to commit to teach, or are you able to be committed to teach?

As per title, there are a lot of verbs which are action verbs vs passive verbs. They are hard to differentiate, is there a rule to it?

Answer (score 3):

In general, use active voice. It's simpler and more direct.

Passive voice dodges responsibility - the action occurred or is expected to occur without specifying who or what is doing it. It is used in bureaucracies to deny responsibility (e.g. "mistakes were made"). It may also be used as a euphemism.

In your example, "are you able to be committed" suggests somebody else might be committing you, rather than you making a commitment, so the active form is definitely better. One meaning of the verb "to commit" is to forcibly detain somebody in a jail or mental health facility [see meanings 2 and 3 for commit in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commit#Verb).

I suggest the simpler "Can you commit to teach...".

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** the idea that the passive voice is a way of "dodging responsibility" or is always "less direct" is a widely debunked myth; see [this article from Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922).

**The answer:**

The Cambridge dictionary defines [commit](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/commit) and [committed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/committed) separately. The latter is *not* in this sense considered the passive voice of the former, since it has a unique meaning as an adjective. Also: both words require a gerund ("to teaching") rather than an infinitive ("to teach"); see [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/554058/commit-to-inf-vs-ing).

So the question is: what is the difference between "to commit to teaching" and "to be committed to teaching"?

"Commit" is defined by that dictionary as:

> to promise or give your loyalty, time, or money to a particular principle, person, or plan of action

So "to commit to teaching" essentially means "to promise that you will teach."

"Committed" is defined as:

> having promised to be involved in a plan of action

So "to be committed to teaching" means "to have promised to be involved in teaching."

So the two have *very* slightly different meanings here. "Are you able to commit to teaching?" means "Can you promise to teach?". "Are you able to be committed to teaching?" means "Can you be someone who has promised to be involved in teaching?". The latter suggests an ongoing, general commitment, whereas the former suggests a more specific one.

If you're asking if someone has what it takes to choose teaching as a career path, you should use: "Are you able to be committed to teaching?"

But if you're asking if someone can teach a particular class on a particular day, you should use: "Are you able to commit to teaching?"